Inserting Frequently Updating fact tables to the data warehouse
I create the data warehouse using SSIS and SQL Server. The data source for the data warehouse is Microsoft Dynamics GP ERP data. In that, there is a table called SOP10100 and SOP10200 (Live Sales Order processing table) which includes frequently updating fact tables. Once the order is completed it is transferred to the historical table deleting the existing record. In my SOP10100 and SOP10200 tables, there are more than 800,000. Hence, I cannot use the truncation method to load the data. Do you have any suggestions on how I can insert these table’s data into the sales fact table in the data warehouse? How suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you.
I tried only truncation method but it takes more than 4 hours to load the data only for these two tables.

The answer is likely going to contain 1) staging the data to a landing area 2) determining  change set 3) applying change set but this is either a project for consultants or you need to read up on the Help Center on how to ask a good question. As it stands, we don't have a reproducible problem here

In addition to what billinkc said, you might look at the Merge statement. I've used it quite a bit for loading/updating large data sets.

There is DEX_ROW_TS field in both SOP10100 and SOP10200 tables, this field
records the date and time the latest change was made to the transactions.
You can first identify the records in SOP10100 and SOP10200 tables modified since your last insertion in fact table and then delete only those records from your fact table and re-insert only those transactions not already exists in fact table from SOP tables. There are different types of Sales Document in this table, you can also filer according to it.

But I insert SOP30200, SOP10100, SOP30300, and SOP10200 into 1 fact table. Once the transaction is completed data from sop10100 and sop10200 will be transferred to the SOP30200 and SOP30300. This can create duplicate entries.

You need to know how data flow in these tables. SOP10100 (SOP Header) and SOP10200  (SOP Line) records un-posted SOP Transactions, where as SOP30200 (SOP Header Posted) and SOP30300 ( SOP Line Posted) holds posted transitions. While transaction is in un-posted tables user can change the data like changing  Item unit Price, Quantity ,UOFM etc. User is able to do changes until unless transaction is posted, once posted it's status changed to POSTED and move to Posted table.

So record which was available in un-posted table now move to posted table, and only available in browse only mode for user in inquiry windows and reports. So record will be either in posted or in unposted table. If it's already inserted in fact table  then by looking posting status you can handle insert operation in fact table. What's your fact table schema? Is it flexible enough to hold both types of transactions?

I add Unposted (SOP10100, SOP10200) data as '0' in the 'Posted' column. And, '1' as 'Posted'(SOP30200, SOP30300) Column. However, the issue is when I add the unposted data to the fact table. After the transaction is posted, it moves to the posted column.
